# Need help making each of these owl objects to bounce around canvas on their own instead of on the same path

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I would like each owl to bounce around the screen on their own                 instead of on the same path

https://editor.p5js.org/nickBG/sketches/_96KYsurS

```js
let rad = 45; // Width of the shape
let xpos, ypos; // Starting position of shape

let xspeed = 6; // Speed of the shape
let yspeed = 5.2; // Speed of the shape

let xdirection = 1.1; // Left or Right
let ydirection = 1.2; // Top to Bottom
let xspeed2 =10
let yspeed2  = 10

function setup() {
  createCanvas(650, 500); //sets up sketch
   noStroke();

  // Set the starting position of the owels
  xpos = width / 2;
  ypos = height / 2;
}

function draw() {
  background(125,155,155);

   for(let x = 30; x < width; x += 80){
    for(let y = 30; y < height; y += 80){
      drawEyes(100, 100);
       drawEyes(125, 100);
    }
  }
  
  // Update the position of the owels
  xpos = xpos + xspeed * xdirection;
  ypos = ypos + yspeed * ydirection;
    
  //*****
  xpos2 = xpos + xspeed * xdirection;
  ypos2 = ypos + yspeed * ydirection;
   //  reverse its direction by multiplying by -1 so owl stays on screen 
  if (xpos > width - rad || xpos < rad) {
    xdirection *= -1;
  }
  if (ypos > height - rad || ypos < rad) {
    ydirection *= -1;
  }

  display(xpos, ypos, 100);

  display(xpos2+100, ypos2, 70);
  display(xpos-130, ypos,150);
  display(xpos, ypos+130,90);
  display(xpos, ypos-120,70);
}

function drawBody(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight) {//creates the body

  fill(139,69,19);//makes the brown body
  stroke(0);
  ellipse(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);

  fill(139,69,19);//makes brown head of owel 
  stroke(0);
  ellipse(owlX, owlY - owlWidth / 4, owlWidth / 1, owlHeight );
}

function drawEyes(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight ){
  fill(255);

  if(random(10) < 9){
    fill(255);
     ellipse(owlX - 15, owlY - owlWidth / 2.4, owlWidth / 1.9, owlHeight);//left whites of eye
    ellipse(owlX + 15, owlY - owlWidth / 2.4, owlWidth / 1.9, owlHeight);//right whites of eye
     fill(0);//right pupil
  noStroke();
  ellipse( owlX + 20 , owlY - owlWidth / 2.5, owlWidth / 10, owlHeight);

//left pupil
  ellipse( owlX - 20 , owlY - owlWidth / 2.5, owlWidth / 10, owlHeight);
  }
  
  else {
    stroke(0);
    line(owlX - 15, owlY - owlWidth / 2.4, owlWidth / 1.9, owlHeight);    
    line(owlX + 15, owlY - owlWidth / 2.4, owlWidth / 1.9, owlHeight);    

  }
}

function drawBeak(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight) {
  fill(60);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight();//creates the  beak 
  triangle(owlX +1, owlY - 20,owlX-8, owlY+ 1,owlX+ 20, owlY +8 );
}

function drawChin(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight) {
  fill(160,82,1);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight();
  ellipse( owlX , owlY - owlWidth / 15, owlWidth / 1.3, owlHeight);//creates the off brown ellipse chin
}


function display(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight) {//draws the owels

  drawBody(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);
  drawChin(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);
  drawEyes(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);
  drawBeak(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating an Owl object that holds speed and direction variables and then randomizing these on creation of the object? Right now it looks like you are just applying the same speed and direction variables to the same object, which would explain what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create arrays of `xpos`, `ypos`, `size`, `xspeed`, `yspeed`, `xdirection` and `ydirection`. The arrays contain individual values for each owl:

```js
let rad = 45; // Width of the shape
let xpos, ypos; // Starting position of shape
let size;

let xspeed; // Speed of the shape
let yspeed; // Speed of the shape

let xdirection; // Left or Right
let ydirection ; // Top to Bottom

function setup() {
    createCanvas(650, 500); //sets up sketch
    noStroke();

    // Set the starting position of the owels
    let x = width / 2;
    let y = height / 2;
    xpos       = [x, x+100, x-120, x, x];
    ypos       = [y, y, y, y+130, y-120];
    size       = [100, 70, 150, 90, 70];
    xdirection = [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1];
    ydirection = [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2];
    xspeed     = [6, 10, 10, 10, 10];
    yspeed     = [5.2, 10, 10, 10, 10];
}
```

The owls can be individually moved and drawn in an loop:

```js
function draw() {
    background(125,155,155);

    for(let x = 30; x < width; x += 80){
        for(let y = 30; y < height; y += 80){
            drawEyes(100, 100);
            drawEyes(125, 100);
        }
    }

    for ( let i = 0; i < xpos.length; ++ i) {
        // Update the position of the owels
        xpos[i] += xspeed[i] * xdirection[i];
        ypos[i] += yspeed[i] * ydirection[i];

        if (xpos[i] > width - rad || xpos[i] < rad) {
            xdirection[i] *= -1;
        }
        if (ypos[i] > height - rad || ypos[i] < rad) {
            ydirection[i] *= -1;
        }
    }

    for ( let i = 0; i < xpos.length; ++ i) {
        display(xpos[i], ypos[i], size[i]);
    }
}
```

See the example, where I applied the changed to your original code:

```js
let rad = 45; // Width of the shape
let xpos, ypos; // Starting position of shape
let size;

let xspeed; // Speed of the shape
let yspeed; // Speed of the shape

let xdirection; // Left or Right
let ydirection ; // Top to Bottom

function setup() {
    createCanvas(650, 500); //sets up sketch
    noStroke();

    // Set the starting position of the owels
    let x = width / 2;
    let y = height / 2;
    xpos       = [x, x+100, x-120, x, x];
    ypos       = [y, y, y, y+130, y-120];
    size       = [100, 70, 150, 90, 70];
    xdirection = [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1];
    ydirection = [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2];
    xspeed     = [6, 10, 10, 10, 10];
    yspeed     = [5.2, 10, 10, 10, 10];
}

function draw() {
    background(125,155,155);

    for(let x = 30; x < width; x += 80){
        for(let y = 30; y < height; y += 80){
            drawEyes(100, 100);
            drawEyes(125, 100);
        }
    }
    
    for ( let i = 0; i < xpos.length; ++ i) {
        // Update the position of the owels
        xpos[i] += xspeed[i] * xdirection[i];
        ypos[i] += yspeed[i] * ydirection[i];

        if (xpos[i] > width - rad || xpos[i] < rad) {
            xdirection[i] *= -1;
        }
        if (ypos[i] > height - rad || ypos[i] < rad) {
            ydirection[i] *= -1;
        }
    }

    for ( let i = 0; i < xpos.length; ++ i) {
        display(xpos[i], ypos[i], size[i]);
    }
}

function drawBody(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight) {//creates the body

  fill(139,69,19);//makes the brown body
  stroke(0);
  ellipse(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);

  fill(139,69,19);//makes brown head of owel 
  stroke(0);
  ellipse(owlX, owlY - owlWidth / 4, owlWidth / 1, owlHeight );
}

function drawEyes(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight ){
  fill(255);

  if(random(10) < 9){
    fill(255);
     ellipse(owlX - 15, owlY - owlWidth / 2.4, owlWidth / 1.9, owlHeight);//left whites of eye
    ellipse(owlX + 15, owlY - owlWidth / 2.4, owlWidth / 1.9, owlHeight);//right whites of eye
     fill(0);//right pupil
  noStroke();
  ellipse( owlX + 20 , owlY - owlWidth / 2.5, owlWidth / 10, owlHeight);

//left pupil
  ellipse( owlX - 20 , owlY - owlWidth / 2.5, owlWidth / 10, owlHeight);
  }
  
  else {
    stroke(0);
    line(owlX - 15, owlY - owlWidth / 2.4, owlWidth / 1.9, owlHeight);    
    line(owlX + 15, owlY - owlWidth / 2.4, owlWidth / 1.9, owlHeight);    

  }
}

function drawBeak(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight) {
  fill(60);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight();//creates the  beak 
  triangle(owlX +1, owlY - 20,owlX-8, owlY+ 1,owlX+ 20, owlY +8 );
}

function drawChin(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight) {
  fill(160,82,1);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight();
  ellipse( owlX , owlY - owlWidth / 15, owlWidth / 1.3, owlHeight);//creates the off brown ellipse chin
}


function display(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight) {//draws the owels

  drawBody(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);
  drawChin(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);
  drawEyes(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);
  drawBeak(owlX, owlY, owlWidth, owlHeight);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```